# What is the adjective to describe someone who views or represents someone/something as a stereotype?

Tags: single-word-requests

What I want to know is whether there is an adjective within the same word family as "stereotype" for that.

So, if it exists, it would be something like "stereotypist" or "stereotyping".

I know that "stereotypist" exists as a noun and "stereotyping" exists as a present participle but I wonder whether either (or both) of them has/have also been used in literature as an adjective.

Comment: [*stereotypical*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stereotypical), perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the word *prejudiced* might help you, in the sense that somebody can have (sometimes false) preconceptions about others. Else, you could describe somebody as '*holding many preconceptions about others*'.

There is also the word *bigot*, used to describe somebody who doesn't listen to others and is often set in their views. The only issue with this, is that somebody who stereotypes seems to want to be described by a "softer" word.